# Autokeras for regression

Tags: keras

I have 2000 samples with 50 sensors signal every millisecond during 600 milliseconds. This means a 2D record for each sample.

I would like to predict a continuous value.

I would like to try autokeras for this regression problem. Could someone point to a tutorial or some advise to start with?

Answer (score 0):

It's buggy but this is what I'm trying to use:

https://github.com/nocluebutalotofit/autokeras/blob/2efe5358f89c279ee4a7d615bb2bdca3e0ced3cb/docs/templates/tutorial/structured_data_regression.md